# Why does std::map::const_iterator call the std::pair constructor during a std::for_each, but a simple for loop does not?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, lambda

I have a slightly complex data member of a class, as noted in what follows:

```
class BranchOutputRow
{
...
}

class Foo
{

public:

    // Slightly complex data member here
    std::map<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int, std::set<BranchOutputRow>> hits;

    void DoLoop1()
    {
        // This loop calls the std::pair<> constructor

        std::for_each(hits.cbegin(), hits.cend(),
        [&](std::pair<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int,
                      std::set<BranchOutputRow>> const & hit)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    void DoLoop2()
    {
        // This loop does NOT call the std::pair<> constructor

        for (std::map<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int,
                      std::set<BranchOutputRow>>::const_iterator hitsPtr 
                    = hits.cbegin();
         hitsPtr != hits.cend();
         ++hitsPtr)
         {
             ...            
         }
    }

}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.hits[1] = std::set<BranchOutputRow>();
    foo.hits[1].insert(BranchOutputRow());

    foo.DoLoop1(); // direct access to map object is not available
    foo.DoLoop2(); // direct access to map object is available
}
```

As noted, I find that Loop #1 calls the `std::pair` constructor, despite the fact that the lambda function accepts its argument by reference.  Therefore, in Loop 1, I do not have direct access to the object in the map, but only a copy.  In my actual program, I need direct access; therefore, I must use the version indicated by Loop 2.

(In fact, Loop 2 does *not* call the `std::pair` constructor - not a surprise - and does provide direct access to the object in the map.)

I would think that `std::for_each` would have been carefully designed to provide the same semantics as a `for` loop such as Loop 2, and therefore not call the `std::pair` constructor, instead allowing direct access to the object in the map.

Why does Loop 1 call the `std::pair` constructor, despite the fact that the lambda function accepts its argument by reference?

Comment: The key type is `const` in the pair, which your lambda parameter does not reflect. I advise using `decltype(hits)::value_type const&`.

Comment: @Xeo - Will the `decltype(hits)::value_type` succeed if `hits` is declared as a `typedef` - for example, `typedef std::map<...> MyMap;`, with `hits` defined as `MyMap hits;`?  I find that it works when there is no `typedef`, but gives a compiler error when there is.  But perhaps I am doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `value_type` of `std::map<K,V>` is `std::pair<const K, V>`. Your lambda takes `std::pair<K,V>`. Note the difference in constness.

The conversion is done through this constructor:

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( const pair<U1, U2>& p );
```

(see (4) on [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair))

The result of the conversion is a temporary, and temporaries can bind to const references, so your code works.

Comment: Thanks - Would `U1` be interpreted by the compiler as `const K`?

Comment: A way to generate an error if you get the types wrong (in some cases) is to rely on piece wise construction of `pair`:  Take a `pair< K const&, V const& >` instead of a `pair<K,V> const&`.  In short, if you are conceptually `tie`ing parameters, take a bundle of references instead of taking a reference to a bundle.  -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0855b93de18a442c -- a simple alias `template<typename... Ts> using cref_tie = std::tuple< const Ts&... >;` makes this even less verbose.